# Do something on the client side when choose dropdown in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a dropdown with some values which are displayed while editing this model in RailsAdmin.

I want to populate some other fields when a user select some value in the dropdown. And I want to populate them on the client side (so a user have a chance to modify these values after fields being populated).

I went through RailsAdmin DSL documentation, but wasn't able to figure out how to include client side (javascript) actions in there.

Any ideas or pointers how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can listen for the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on the dropdown and then set the value of the input(s) you want to populate using [`jQuery.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thanks. However, my question is more about figuring out where should I put the code (taking into RailsAdmin handling generation of whole page) vs how to capture some event.

Comment: @VictorRonin You should be able to just [override custom/ui.js](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1089) and add the javascript you want.